# Spring Boot test mock bean

Tags: spring, testing, mockito

How mock 2 beans when one is into second ?

```
public class A {
...
}

public class B {
private A a;
}
```

I tried:

```
@MockBean 
private A a;

@InjectMocks 
private B b;

@Before
public void executedBeforeEach() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

but had exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'B'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to     construct the instance.
However, I failed because: the type 'B' is an interface.
```

spring version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

test dependency:

```
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

how to do it right  ?where did I make a mistake ?

Comment: according to the exception.. B is an interface.. it cannot have dependencies..

Comment: Class 'B' is not by any change an interface like the exception message says?
Also, do not use `@MockBean`, use `@Mock` instead.
And instead of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(b);`

Comment: i understand than you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to autowire B. By using the annotation `@MockBean` you are telling the test Spring context to replace the actual bean of type A with a mock and this will automatically be injected into everywhere A in included (i.e. in your B bean).

```
@MockBean 
private A a;

@Autowire
private B b;
```

This is under the assumption that you are annotating your test class with `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: If you are mocking B then there is no reason to mock A because you are just mocking the behaviour of B anyway

Comment: i.e. any calls to methods on A inside B won't actually happen if you mock B so it doesnt matter